# Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options)

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I am using sf package to do some geospatial analysis on a geodatabase. But Whenever I try to save the results as shapefile, I get

> ```
> "Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
> as.character(dataset_options)".
> ```

Even when I try to write the shapefile right after reading it (see the code below), I still get this error:

```
WMain_19 <- read_sf("./seg_19a.shp")
write_sf(WMain_19, "WMain19a.shp")
```

The shapefile is a linestring.

Comment: ```st_write(WMain_19, "WMain19a.shp", append = FALSE)```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `read_sf` followed by `write_sf` works perfectly for me using a shapefile on my machine, so maybe its something to do with your data, which we don't have. Can you share your data or at least show `summary(WMain_19)` after reading it in case its corrupted somehow. Otherwise we're all guessing in the dark.